# SQL Query to get xml node values from nvarchar column is very slow

Tags: xml, vba, find, duplicates, xmlnode

I have one table called tblAdmissions, one of the column in this table is called "ProgramInformation". This column contain xml string like

```
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" num="1">

  <COURSE>reference_project</COURSE>

  <FEE>true</FEE>

</row>

<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" num="2">
  <COURSE>RoomID</COURSE>
  <FEE>99</FEE>

</row>
```

I am using this query to get values from this columns by using cross apply and its very slow.

With vDynamic AS (
            Select

```
            xmlProgramInformation = CAST(ProgramInformation AS XML)
        FROM 
            tblAdmission

        )

SELECT 

  t.p.query('COURSE' ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS Decipline, 
  t.p.query('FEE' ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS CourseFee 

FROM 
  vDynamic 
  CROSS apply xmlProgramInformation.nodes('/DOCUMENT/ROWS/row') AS t(p)
```

Is there any other method so that my query can run fast.

Thanks

Comment: Any one knows some better solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you can try, starting from easiest to implement to most difficult:

1. If all of your data is in XML, then change the nvarchar to an XML column. I'm relatively certain that this won't have a noticeable impact on your performance, but it's foundational for the next steps.
2. Implement an XML index.  Check Books OnLine for details
3. If the attributes that you are querying are fixed, then you may want to go ahead and shred them into a fixed table format.  SQL Server prefers SQL; XML and XQuery should be used for ad-hoc exploration and/or transformative work.

Comment: Hi, Thnaks for your reply. My data is not based on xml. I have one to many relationship,, and I want to get data from detail table in one row, thats why I am using xml. My original table dont have XML column. As you can see above, the course and fee column are from detail table with nvarchar data type. I have written one view in which I got all the attribute from detail table in xml formate based on Parent table(1 to many)